# How to merge xml files with different elements/nodes into a single file using PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell

I am trying to merge 3 xml files into 1 using PowerShell.
I have tried a number of ways using Select-Xml, CreateElement followed by AppendChild etc but can't seem to understand how to get the elements I want to be included correctly into s new XML Document. I either get an empty resultant file or System.Xml.Element in the nodes.

The three files have the contents:
File A

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ResourceResponse>
<Status>Success</Status>
 <Resource id="12345" name="aName" description="Microsoft Windows 2008" location="" instanceId="10003" typeId="1">
 <Agent id="23456" address="x.x.x.x" port="2144" version="x.x.x" unidirectional="false" />
 <Ip address="x.x.x.x" netmask="255.0.0.0" mac="00:00:00:00:00:00" />
 <Ip address="x.x.x.x" netmask="255.255.240.0" mac="00:50:56:03:40:E2" />
 <ResourceInfo key="fqdn" value="aName.here.lo" />
 </Resource>
</ResourceResponse>
```

File B

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ResourcePrototypeResponse>
<Status>Success</Status>
<ResourcePrototype instanceId='10164' resourceTypeId='3' id='10213' name='TCP Socket'/>
</ResourcePrototypeResponse>
```

File C

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <Resource name="SocketHTTP">
            <ResourceConfig key="hostname" value="localhost"/>
            <ResourceConfig key="port" value="80"/>
            <ResourceConfig key="sotimeout" value="10"/>
            <ResourceConfig key="service.log_track.enable" value="false"/>
            <ResourceConfig key="service.log_track.level" value="Error"/>
            <ResourceConfig key="service.log_track.include" value=""/>
            <ResourceConfig key="service.log_track.exclude" value=""/>
            <ResourceInfo key="autoIdentifier" value="SocketHTTP"/>
        </Resource>
```

I would like the created file to look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<CreateResourceRequest>
<Resource id="12345" name="aName" description="Microsoft Windows 2008" location="" instanceId="10087" typeId="1">
 <Agent id="23456" address="x.x.x.x" port="2144" version="x.x.x" unidirectional="false"/>
  <Ip address="x.x.x.x" netmask="255.255.255.0"/>
  <Ip address="x.x.x.x" netmask="255.0.0.0"/>
 <ResourceInfo key="fqdn" value="aName.here.lo"/>
 </Resource>
 <ResourcePrototype instanceId="10164" resourceTypeId="3" id="10213" name="TCP Socket"/>
      <Resource name="SocketHTTP">
            <ResourceConfig key="hostname" value="target.here.lo"/>
            <ResourceConfig key="port" value="80"/>
            <ResourceConfig key="sotimeout" value="10"/>
            <ResourceConfig key="service.log_track.enable" value="false"/>
            <ResourceConfig key="service.log_track.level" value="Error"/>
            <ResourceConfig key="service.log_track.include" value=""/>
            <ResourceConfig key="service.log_track.exclude" value=""/>
            <ResourceInfo key="autoIdentifier" value="SocketHTTP"/>
        </Resource>

</CreateResourceRequest>
```

Thanks in advance, I'm stumped....

Answer (score 2):

You need something like this:

```
function Add-XmlFromFile ([String]$Path,
                          [String]$XPath,
                          [System.Xml.XmlElement]$ParentElement) {

    [System.Xml.XmlElement]$ChildElement = `
        (Select-Xml -Path $Path -XPath $XPath).Node

    [System.Xml.XmlElement]$ImportedElement = `
        $ParentElement.OwnerDocument.ImportNode($ChildElement, $true)

    return $ParentElement.AppendChild($ImportedElement)
}

# Creating new XML object.
$Xml = New-Object Xml
$XmlDeclaration = $Xml.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", $null)
$Xml.AppendChild($XmlDeclaration) | Out-Null

# Creating parent element.
$CreateResourceRequest = $Xml.CreateElement("CreateResourceRequest")

# Adding child elements to parent.
Add-XmlFromFile -Path "File A.xml" `
    -XPath "//ResourceResponse/Resource" `
    -ParentElement $CreateResourceRequest | Out-Null
Add-XmlFromFile -Path "File B.xml" `
    -XPath "//ResourcePrototypeResponse/ResourcePrototype" `
    -ParentElement $CreateResourceRequest | Out-Null
Add-XmlFromFile -Path "File C.xml" `
    -XPath "//Resource" `
    -ParentElement $CreateResourceRequest | Out-Null

# Appending parent to XML object.
$Xml.AppendChild($CreateResourceRequest) | Out-Null

# Saving XML object.
$Xml.OuterXml | Out-File -FilePath "File D.xml" -Encoding "UTF8"
```

Comment: Works perfectly!
Not only that but I know understand it a bit better.
Wish I would have asked sooner...
Thanks again.

Comment: So close.....
I see that $Xml.AppendChild($XmlDeclaration) | Out-Null inserts 3 bytes before '<?xml..' when writing the file.
I wrote the file before adding an additional children and it is coming from that operation. 
I made sure to set the encoding to utf8 as in: OutFile -Encoding utf8 but I still get:
<bh:ef><bh:bb><bh:bf>\<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Am I not setting something correctly?

Comment: Added `-Encoding "UTF8"` - indeed by default PS uses UCS-2 Little Endian encoding. However, I cannot reproduce the issue (in PS 2.0) neither with UCS-2 nor with UTF-8 - I don't see any additional characters in the file my code generates.

Comment: Thanks Alexander.

I'm using PS4 (after upgrading to get beyind the PS3 Invoke-RestMethod bug around the Headers).
I also added the -Encoding uft8 switch as the payload ended up as Unicode and I needed plain text.
It seems to be an artifact of the way files are written. I found some info about the stream encoding that causes this.
I confirmed the data in the file with a hex editor as well as a tcpdump.

I've decided to just write the payload directly rather than saving it first. (Should've done that all along!)

Thanks again for your quick reply!